# Showing continuity for trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, continuity

I came across a question involving continuous extension of a trigonometric function:
$$ \frac{\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})\sin^3x}{x} $$  if $ x \lt 0$
and $$x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$$
if $x \ge 0 $. How do we go about showing that it is continuous at 0? I know you have to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$ = $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$, but not really sure how to find the answer for $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})\sin^3x}{x}$. Is it possible to explain step by step?

Comment: Use squeeze theorem and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin x}x = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fact 1* $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

*Fact 2* $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$ (since $|\frac{\sin x}{x}|\le 1/|x|\to0$).
Equivalently, $\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$.

Then $$\frac{\sin^2(\frac{1}{x})\sin^3x}{x}=\left(x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^3\to0^2\times1^3=0$$